# how to go to running in Application manager in settings in android device programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, settings

I want to get the ram usage of all the running applications. I've tried many times to get the ram usage of all the running applications but I'm able to get the ram usage of my own application. I'm able to go to Settings>Application manager>Download and All through my code, but I'm unable to reach Settings>Application manager>Running by my code. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link to determine data usage per application programmatically [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android). You will need to implement your code using [MemoryInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html) class.